# Horizontal alignment in <v-data-table> from Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following table in which I can't align some items such as the checkbox and the actions:
[image]

This is the table:

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
        hide-actions
        class="elevation-1"
>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.empresa.descripcion}}</td>
        <v-checkbox disabled v-model="props.item.isAdmin"></v-checkbox> 
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.createdAt }}</td>
        <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
            <v-icon
                    small
                    class="mr-2"
                    @click="editItem(props.item)"
            >
                Editar
            </v-icon>
            <v-icon
                    small
                    left
                    class="mr-2"
                    @click="deleteItem(props.item)"
            >
                Eliminar
            </v-icon>
        </td>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

I need to align the `v-checkbox` and the `v-icon`.

There is no css in the `<style>` section.

Comment: Wrap them in a `<v-layout justify-center></v-layout>`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy how exactly? i got this weird result: https://imgur.com/uudHL3I  https://pastebin.com/uDfUQNzF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give it a try wrapping the `<v-layout justify-center></v-layout>` with `<td></td>` like the Ohgodwhy comment.

It would be like:

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
        hide-actions
        class="elevation-1"
>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>
            <v-layout justify-center>
                {{ props.item.email }}
            </v-layout>
        </td>
        <td>
            <v-layout justify-center>
                {{ props.item.empresa.descripcion}}
            </v-layout>
        </td>
        <td>
            <v-layout justify-center>
                <v-checkbox disabled v-model="props.item.isAdmin"></v-checkbox>
            </v-layout>
        </td>
        <td>
            <v-layout justify-center>
                {{ props.item.createdAt }}
            </v-layout>
        </td>
        <td>
            <v-layout justify-center>
                <v-icon
                    small
                    class="mr-2"
                    @click="editItem(props.item)"
                >
                    Editar
                </v-icon>
                <v-icon
                    small
                    left
                    class="mr-2"
                    @click="deleteItem(props.item)"
                >
                    Eliminar
                </v-icon>
            </v-layout>
        </td>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you taking a simple example from the Vuetify docs like I did:

```
<v-card>
 <v-card-title id="balloon-title">Balloon Info - tracking [balloon ID]</v-card-title>
 <v-data-table disable-sort dense hide-default-footer :headers="headers" :items="info" item-key="name">
 </v-data-table>
</v-card>
```

The solution above requires you to change your entire layout. Instead, I styled the `td` selector like so

```
td {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!

edit- make sure this style isn't in a scoped component.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified snippet that iterates `<td>` instead of specifying each prop, using only the css class `text-center` instead of a whole `v-layout` component:

```
<v-data-table
  item-key="yourItemKey"
  :items="dataSet" 
  :headers="headers">

  <!-- item is the row itself with the column values -->
  <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
      <tr>
          <td v-for="(val, key) in item" :key="key" class="text-center">
              {{ val }}
          </td>
      </tr>
  </template>

</v-data-table>
```